# Error in passing array data to createChatCompletion ChatGPT

Tags: javascript, chatgpt-api

I am exploring chatGPT API Documentation. I created a following array and sending it to generate response from the ChatGPT API. It works fine.

But whenever I am pushing an object inside that array and then sending it to the ChatGPT API it is showing an error.

```js
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'Your OPENAI_API_KEY',
});

const chatGPTProvider = async () => {
  try {
    const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';

    let data = [
      { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' },
      {
        role: 'user',
        content: 'Act as an intelligent AI.',
      },
    ];

    // data.push({ role: 'sytem', content: 'Hola GPT' });

    // console.log(data);

    const resp = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: data,
    });

    return { status: 'SUCCESS', result: resp.data.choices[0].message };
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);

    return { status: 'ERROR', result: null };
  }
};
```

This code works fine. When you uncomment that push method it starts giving error.

Can you please tell why only pushing data into the array results in error?

Documentation: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create?lang=node.js

I am getting the following Error
Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (/home/sushant007/Interview-Project/GPT-chatbot/server/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (/home/sushant007/Interview-Project/GPT-chatbot/server/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/sushant007/Interview-Project/GPT-chatbot/server/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:524:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1378:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: on your data.push method there is a typo on system, might there is a n issue, although I have not tried yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `JSON.stringify()` because the ChatGPT API is calling `JSON.parse()` on an already-parsed object, which should be throwing an error.

```js
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'Your OPENAI_API_KEY',
});

const chatGPTProvider = async () => {
  try {
    const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';

    let data = [
      { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' },
      {
        role: 'user',
        content: 'Act as an intelligent AI.',
      },
    ];

    data.push(JSON.stringify({ role: 'sytem', content: 'Hola GPT' }));

    console.log(data);

    const resp = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: data,
    });

    return { status: 'SUCCESS', result: resp.data.choices[0].message };
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);

    return { status: 'ERROR', result: null };
  }
};
```

The 400 status code probably means malformed or strange syntax that the server can't parse. So I'm assuming that's what the problem is, so try the `JSON.stringify()` method.

Comment: I am still getting the same Error.

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 400 at createError (/home/sushant007/Interview-Project/GPT-chatbot/server/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15) at settle (/home/sushant007/Interview-Project/GPT-chatbot/server/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12) at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/sushant007/Interview-Project/GPT-chatbot/server/node_modules/openai/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11) at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:524:35) at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1378:12) at process.process

Comment: Oh, that sucks. I thought for sure that would fix it. I'm not experienced with the ChatGPT API so I don't know what else you could do